# Simple arrays and for loops. Skipping an input.

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, count

I need to create a for loop that fills 2 arrays I have set up. However whenever I run the program. It keeps skipping the next prompt and read in and I have no idea why?
My code is below. It skips the part where I ask them to enter a sentance/word.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * Date: 18/02/2015
 * Time: 15:33
 * UPDATE COMMENT ABOUT PROGRAM HERE
 */
public class Week5Q2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      final int HOWMANY=5;
      Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
      int choice;

      int number [] = new int [5];//mechanism1
      String sentence [] = new String [5];


      for(int count=0;count<HOWMANY;count++)
      {

         System.out.println("Please enter a number below");
         number[count]=keyboard.nextInt();


         System.out.println("\nPlease enter a word below");
         sentence[count]=keyboard.nextLine();


      }//for

      System.out.println("Thank you, now press 1 if you wish to see what you have entered");
      choice=keyboard.nextInt();

      switch(choice)
      {
         case 1:

            for(int count=0;count<HOWMANY;count++)
            {
               System.out.println("Here are your numbers");
               System.out.println("\n" + number[count]);

               System.out.println("Here are your words");
               System.out.println("\n" + sentence[count]);

            }//for
      }//switch




   }//main
}//class
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call `nextLine()` after `nextInt()`, to consume the end of the line that contained the int. Otherwise, the end of the line will be consumed when you expect to read the sentence/word.

```
  for(int count=0;count<HOWMANY;count++)
  {

     System.out.println("Please enter a number below");
     number[count]=keyboard.nextInt();

     keyboard.nextLine();

     System.out.println("\nPlease enter a word below");
     sentence[count]=keyboard.nextLine();


  }//for
```